# How to change domain of url using fetch method?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have some basic form:

```js
var formElem = document.getElementById("some_basic_form");
formElem.onsubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let fullUrl = document.getElementById('shorten_url').value
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fullUrl', fullUrl);

  let response = await fetch('/url-shortenerer/create', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });

  let result = await response.json();

  alert(result.message);
};
```

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8080" method="post" id="some_basic_form">
  Full url: <input id="shorten_url">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to send a POST request to the backend service, but I see, that request sent via `63342` port, not `8080`. How to solve it?

Comment: your front app run under the port `63342` , try using `await fetch('http://localhost:8080/url-shortenerer/create'...` or  `await fetch(formElem.action+'/url-shortenerer/create'...`

Comment: You want to send the request to 8080?

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD yes

Comment: @Spring it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think providing the mode property with the init object will fix the CORS errors.

```
let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/url-shortenerer/create", { 
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```